# solving $\frac{d}{dx}(2^x+3^x\cos(\pi x))=0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, roots

is there any "elementary" method to solve this equation

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\big(2^x+3^x\cos(\pi x)\big)=0
\end{align}

I tried to use wolfram alpha for solutions but it couldn't do it.

Comment: This is equivalent to $(2/3)^x\ln2+\ln3\cdot\cos\pi x-\pi\sin\pi x=0$. Only numerical methods can solve that.

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, finding the zeros of function
$$f(x)=a^x\log (2)-\pi  \sin (\pi  x)+\log (3)   \cos (\pi  x) \qquad \text{where}\qquad a=\frac 23$$ needs numerical methods.

However, you probably noticed already that the solutions are closer and closer to integer values. So, let $x=n+t$
$$f(t)= a^{n+t}\log (2)+(-1)^n (\log (3) \cos (\pi  t)-\pi  \sin (\pi  t))$$

Expand $f(t)$ around $t=0$
$$f(t)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{b_k}{k!}\,t^k$$ where the first coefficients are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & b_k \\
 0 & \log (2) a^n+(-1)^n \log (3) \\
 1 & \log (2) a^n \log (a)-\pi ^2 (-1)^n \\
 2 & \log (2) a^n \log ^2(a)-\pi ^2 (-1)^n \log (3) \\
 3 & \log (2) a^n \log ^3(a)+\pi ^4 (-1)^n \\
 4 & \log (2) a^n \log ^4(a)+\pi ^4 (-1)^n \log (3) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, use [power series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) to make
$$t=-\frac{\log (2) a^n+(-1)^n \log (3)}{\log (2) a^n \log (a)-\pi ^2
   (-1)^n}-$$
$$\frac{\left(\log (2) a^n+(-1)^n \log (3)\right)^2 \left(\log (2) a^n
   \log ^2(a)-\pi ^2 (-1)^n \log (3)\right)}{2 \left(\log (2) a^n
   \log (a)-\pi ^2 (-1)^n\right)^3}+\cdots$$

Using only the terms given in the above table, some results (do not forget to add $n$ to $t_{(n)}$ in order to have  $x_{(n)}$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 0.063864 &  0.063883 \\
 2 & 0.134349 &  0.135012 \\
 3 & 0.088028 &  0.088117 \\
 4 & 0.119182 &  0.119560 \\
 5 & 0.098540 &  0.098693 \\
 6 & 0.112356 &  0.112642 \\
 7 & 0.103170 &  0.103361 \\
 8 & 0.109305 &  0.109556 \\
  9 & 0.105220 &  0.105429 \\
 10 & 0.107945 &  0.108182 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ and we could do much better adding a few more terms.

When $n$ will be very large, the term $a^{n+t}$ will be neglible and
$$\log (3) \cos (\pi  t)-\pi  \sin (\pi  t)\sim 0\quad \implies \quad t_{(\infty)}=\frac 1 \pi \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\log (3)}{\pi }\right)=0.107082$$

**Edit**

If you want to have a good explicit *approximation*, use one single iteration of Newton method starting with $t_0=t_{(\infty)}$. This will give

$$t_1=t_0-\frac{f(t_0)}{f'(t_0)}$$ which not ugly at all since
$$f(t_0)=\log (2) a^{n+\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\log (3)}{\pi }\right)}{\pi
   }}$$ and
$$f'(t_0)=\log (2) \log (a) a^{n+\frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\log (3)}{\pi
   }\right)}{\pi }}-\pi  (-1)^n \sqrt{\pi ^2+\log ^2(3)}$$

Thsi will give
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 0.0640247402 &  0.0638833045 \\
 2 & 0.1349745836 &  0.1350117865 \\
 3 & 0.0881290392 &  0.0881171739 \\
 4 & 0.1195568672 &  0.1195602065 \\
 5 & 0.0986940499 &  0.0986930271 \\
 6 & 0.1126417901 &  0.1126420864 \\
 7 & 0.1033608318 &  0.1033607427 \\
 8 & 0.1095558965 &  0.1095559227 \\
 9 & 0.1054293120 &  0.1054293042 \\
 10 & 0.1081819025 &  0.1081819025 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$